# Error "cannot open source file "gnu/stubs-soft.h"" from Visual Studio Code's Intellisense for cmake cross-compilation project

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, yocto

I am using *Visual Studio Code* to work on a project for an *Arm* processor. *Cmake* and a *Yocto*-generated toolchain are used for building. Everything runs in a *devcontainer*.
I have defined a *Cmake* kit in `.vscode/cmake-kits.json` which looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Name of toolchain",
    "environmentSetupScript": "<base-path>/environment-setup-armv7vet2hf-neon-oe-linux-gnueabi",
    "preferredGenerator": {
      "name": "Unix Makefiles"
    },
    "toolchainFile": "<base-path>/sysroots/x86_64-oesdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake"
  }
]
```

Building the project is not a problem at all. But *Intellisense* keeps producing this error message "cannot open source file "gnu/stubs-soft.h"" for a lot of `#include` directives.

The file `.vscode/c_cpp_prperties.json` currently looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "compileCommands": "${config:cmake.sourceDirectory}/build/compile_commands.json"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I have unsuccessfully played around with all possible options inside this file.
I would highly appreciate any tips to get rid of this message.

Comment: where exactly is `gnu/stubs-soft.h` located in the container? Is it supposed to be added explicitly in an include flag? Or is it implicit by the compiler?

Comment: I think it is an implicit file. It seems to be related to floating point emulation and should not be used on target that have floating point hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the `configurationProvider` property to `"ms-vscode.cpptools"` in `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "compileCommands": "${config:cmake.sourceDirectory}/build/compile_commands.json",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```